# How to properly place a Page indicator.?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

I have created this page indicator but i could not get it to a right position. I want it to be in the middle of the image or at the bottom of the image but it is at the very top near the back button and I tried but could not change its position.

Here is the image of the activity:

[image]

Here is the xml of the activity I am using. The Page indicator View as you see is under View Pager. Any type of help would be appreciated.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#424242"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/appbar_header_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/activity_margin_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">




        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <com.rd.PageIndicatorView
            android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:piv_animationType="worm"
            app:piv_dynamicCount="true"
            app:piv_interactiveAnimation="true"
            app:piv_selectedColor="@color/gray_50"
            app:piv_unselectedColor="@color/gray_300"
            app:piv_viewPager="@id/viewPager"
            attrs:piv_padding="12dp"
            attrs:piv_radius="8dp" />







        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/scrim"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_margin_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_margin_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:listItem="@layout/item_dessert"/>
```

viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

```
    myCustomPagerAdapter = new MyCustomPagerAdapter(AnimateToolbar.this, images);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myCustomPagerAdapter);

    final PageIndicatorView pageIndicatorView = findViewById(R.id.pageIndicatorView);


    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {/*empty*/}

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            pageIndicatorView.setSelection(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {/*empty*/}
    });
```

the attrs are just the resources i have defined for how big the PageIndicatorView is it has nothing to do with its original positioning.

Comment: `PageIndicatorView` can be positioned 100% same as any other view.

Comment: Can you giva me a code Example please.

Comment: that depends on which layout are those 2 views placed into.

Comment: A Collapsing Toolbar Layout which is in an App bar Layout

Comment: can you please put whole layout code

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/activity_margin_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

under this are the View pager and page indicator view mentioned above.

Comment: it's impossible to read it. Edit the question and add the code instead